# How to check email (confirmed/or no) at login in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I use a standart Laravel Authentication.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But I need to check the status of the user email (confirmed/not confirmed). If not confirmed, then an error will be shown in the login page.

**Laravel 5.2**

Thanks!

Comment: Field in the database - confirm (1/0).
I understand that it is necessary to look towards Middleware, but I do not understand how to make this check.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.WCPkZB8xA8o). It's for `L5.2`, but it should work for `L5.3` as well.

Comment: Dear OP, since you marked the answer as acceptable, could you, please, elaborate on why did you do that. If you were able to adapt the code in the answer, please, share your completed solution, so other visitors could find this helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a column `is_verified` and another column `verification_hash` in `users` table.  In `AuthController.php`

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'verification_hash' => md5($data['name'] . Carbon::now()->timestamp),
        'is_verified' => 0,
    ]);
   }
```

override `register` method to send him mail with Verification link

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);

    // Send verification email
    // use $user->verification_hash to generate link
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Now this verification link should look like below as it contain a hash specific to that user

```
http://your_domain.com/auth/verify/6d533b7664483d3cadd13c23477e4f12
```

on this link method, change `is_verified` to 1 for that user.

Now modify your `validator` method like this

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'is_verified'=>'in:1'
    ]);
}
```

This will allow only those users to login who have `is_verified` value as 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? The code makes no sense... This will not deny you login if not verified, and what is the point of `'is_verified'=>'in:1` in validator? Mail send, is_verified update, is_verified check, custom error exception throw, all not implemented...

Comment: I am guessing this code is cropped from some 3rd-party Laravel verification plugin.

Comment: Dude, calm down. This code is indigenously developed by me for this particular problem. you can always modify code according to your need if you have any problem.

Comment: If by "modify code according to your need" you mean "write the code that will actually work", than sure. Otherwise, these are just random lines of code that have "something to do" with OP's question. Also, you didn't answer any of my questions - is this because you don't know, or...?

Comment: If its not working for you that mean you have messed up somewhere... because https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules tells how `in` works in validation. Please check your code again and let me know.

Comment: I do not need this code myself, I am just evaluating your answer. Should I just repeat my answer to you, then?  What is the point of `'is_verified'=>'in:1` in validator? And while we are at this `'is_verified' => 0,` also irrelevant, since `Make a column is_verified with default value 0`, remember?